# Vary colors of axis labels in R based on another variable

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I usually use ggplot2, but in this case I am using the regular `image()` function to plot a heatmap of a large data set. I can label *all* the labels as red, but I want to label the y-axis with text of different colors based on a vector of color definitions that I generate:

```
grid = structure(c(1:12),.Dim = c(4,3))
labs = c("A","B","C")
image(1:4,1:3,grid,axes=FALSE, xlab="", ylab = "")
#This works but isn't the colors I want
axis(2,at=1:length(labs),labels=labs,las=2, adj=1,cex.axis=0.6,col.axis="red")
```

That generates the following image:

[image: Example plot]

I would like labels A and C to be black and B to be red. This is what I tried, but it gives a "wrong length" error...

```
axiscolors = c("black","red","black")
axis(2,at=1:length(labs),labels=labs,las=2, adj=1, cex.axis=0.6, col.axis=axiscolors)
```

This is the effect I am after with some "real" data...

[image: actual heatmap]

**EDIT:**

As a back-up, if this is possible in ggplot2, I might be willing to re-factor my code. There are a couple other applications I would use this for as well.

I figured out a way to plot a layer of red symbols over the top of the old labels, but would prefer a native method with the color vector, if possible...

```
sublabs = c("B")
axis(2,at=match(sublabs,labs),labels=sublabs,las=2, adj=1, cex.axis=0.6, col.axis="red")
```

Another way would be to use `text()` if I could put the labels outside the plot space...

```
text(c(1,1,1),c(1,2,3),labs,col=c("black","red","black"))
```

**UPDATE:** See below for a solution that works with `ggplot2`...

Comment: I do not think you will find a "native method". There is a fairly strong cultural resistance among the R authors toward what some people would call "chart junk".

Comment: Interesting. I am a die-hard Tufte-an, but one person's "chart junk" is another person's information. (In the non-toy example I have 91 values on the y axis and am labeling the 16 newly interspersed rows to highlight where they come out.)

Comment: I did look at the code that is exposed to a regular user and did not see anything that could be hacked in pure R for `graphics::axis`. I wonder if grid graphics might provide an avenue. I see that there is a lattice version of `lattice::axis.default` and it looks like the 'do.labels' section would be promising. You might need to also hack  `lattice::panel.axis`.

Comment: `?mtext` instead of `?text` would be the way to go.

Comment: Perhaps you could use `layout` to create independent axis labels and position them close to the original graph with no axis labels.  But that seems like more work than plotting a layer of new symbols over the old symbols.  Maybe you could position your `text` statement outside the plot area using `outer`, `inset` and/or `mar`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you ignore the vectorised possibilities like `text` and `mtext`, you can get there by repeatedly calling `axis`. The overhead timewise will be very minimal and it will allow all the `axis` calculations to occur as they normally do. E.g.:

```
# original code
grid = structure(c(1:12),.Dim = c(4,3))
labs = c("A","B","C")
image(1:4,1:3,grid,axes=FALSE, xlab="", ylab = "")
axiscolors = c("black","red","black")

# new code    
Map(axis, side=2, at=1:3, col.axis=axiscolors, labels=labs, lwd=0, las=1)
axis(2,at=1:3,labels=FALSE)
```

Resulting in:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I like this solution since it seems to scale well and uses the natural `axis()` command rather than tweaking the position of `text`.

Comment: Just tried this with `mtext`, works great too!

Answer (score 5):

Accepting @thelatemail's answer as the most flexible, but it also turns out to be pretty simple using `text()` if you add `xpd = TRUE` to allow plotting outside the frame. Using `mtext()` can also work, but it doesn't allow you to [rotate labels](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-can-I-create-rotated-axis-labels_003f).

```
grid = structure(c(1:20),.Dim = c(4,5))
labs = c("A","B","C","D","E")
redlabs = c("B","D")
colorlist = c("black","red")
# one of many ways to generate the color labels
axiscolor = colorlist[labs %in% redlabs +1 ]

image(1:4,1:5,grid,axes=FALSE, xlab="", ylab = "")
axis(2,at=1:length(labs),labels=FALSE)

# This would work for sideways labels
# mtext(text=labs, side=2,at=1:length(labs),col=axiscolor,adj=.5)
text(labels=labs, col=axiscolor, x=rep(.45,length(labs)), y=1:length(labs), srt = 0, pos = 2, xpd = TRUE)
```

[image: Solution using text()]

**UPDATE for ggplot2**: You can use `theme()` and `element_text` to set the colors and other parameters. Something like this...

```
 p + theme(axis.text.y = element_text(color=axiscolor))
```

Answer (score 3):

You could specify a vector with the colors you want to apply to the labels and then use a loop to get the labels colored with axis(). In the following example, I use a different color for each level of a dot chart.

```
DF <- data.frame(habitat=c("Hab 1","Hab 2","Hab 3","Hab 4","Hab 5"), mean=c(0.53,0.28,0.30,0.35,0.39), color=colors()[c(24,257,26,504,652)])
> DF
habitat mean      color
1   Hab 1 0.53      black
2   Hab 2 0.28     green3
3   Hab 3 0.30       blue
4   Hab 4 0.35 orangered1
5   Hab 5 0.39     yellow

par(mar=c(7, 5, 4, 3))
dotchart(DF[,2], xlim=c(0.2,0.6), col=as.character(DF$color), pch=16, lcolor="white", xlab=colnames(DF[2])) # Plot the points 
for (j in 1:5){
axis(side=2, at=j, col.axis=as.character(DF$color)[j], labels=DF$habitat[j], las=1) # Add habitat as labels, each with corresponding color, on the left margin
}
```

Comment: That could work. I just wish there was a way to do it as a vector instead of looping: `axis(side=2, at=as.numeric(DF$habitat), col.axis=as.character(DF$color), labels=DF$habitat, las=1)`

Answer (score 2):

I like very much thelatemail's approach, and can only add a small refinement since the fixed "at" positions (as in the example above with `at = 1:3`) didn't work well for me. In my case, I needed to generate a barplot and provided my own values for space and width parameters. In the end what I used looks like (example with random data in which I wanted the bars and labels for positive (non-negative, to be more precise) data values to be green and red otherwise. For this example I also use the `letters` function to provide labels and rotate the labels using `las = 2`):

```
x <- rnorm(26)
color <- rep("green", length(x))
color[x < 0] <- "red"

par(mar=c(6,4.1,4.1,2.1))
barplot(x, las = 2, ylim = c(min(x)-0.5, max(x)+0.5), col = color, space = 0.5, width = 2)    
Map(function(x,y,z) 
axis(1,at=x,col.axis=y,labels=z,lwd=0,las=2),
seq(from = 2, by = 3, length.out = length(x)),
color,
letters
)
axis(1,at=seq(from = 2, by = 3, length.out = length(x)),labels=FALSE)
```

Comment: Just so you know, you can save the midpoints of each bar as a returned value like: `bp <- barplot(x, las = 2, ylim = c(min(x)-0.5, max(x)+0.5), col = color, space = 0.5, width = 2)` , which will remove the need to specify the `seq`uence of points manually.