# Changing color of axis() labels individually in base R?

Tags: r, plot

I'm wondering how to turn the color of the *y-axis label* for the **first** and the **last** label to `"red"` (*see picture below*)?

Here is what I tried without success:

```
plot(1:5, yaxt = "n")

axis(2, at = 1:5, labels = paste0("case ", 1:5), col.axis = c(2, rep(1, 3), 2))
```

[image]

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839731/vary-colors-of-axis-labels-in-r-based-on-another-variable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`col.axis` isn't vectorised, so you'd need to do it as two commands. First I've done all the annotations in black, then overplotted the ends in red.

```
plot(1:5, yaxt = "n")
axis(2, at = 1:5, labels = paste0("case ", 1:5), col.axis = 1)
axis(2, at = range(1:5), labels = paste0("case ", range(1:5)), col.axis = 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a more generic example:

```
palette ( c ( "steelblue", "orange" ))

X <- 1:5
Cols <- rep ( 1, length ( X ))
Cols [ c ( 1, length ( X ))] <- 2

plot ( X, yaxt = "n" )
axis ( 2, at = X, labels = FALSE )
mtext ( paste ( "Case", X ), at = pretty ( X ),
  side = 2, line = 1, col = Cols )
```

[image]

I hope it helps.

David