# How can I change the colors of the title and labels in a heatmap in r (basic)?

Tags: r, colors, heatmap

*** Does anyone know how I can change color of the title and labels from black to white? I tried col.main(), col.axis(), col.lab(), but unfortuntly it does not work.**

[image]

```
dev.off()
par(mar=c(5.5,8,6,2.1), bg ="#0C2F67", las=1,lty=0, fg = "ghostwhite")
attach(hart_test)
hart_order <- hart_test[order(hart_test$Leeftijd),]
hart_matrix <- data.matrix(hart_order)
heatmap(hart_matrix, Colv = NA, Rowv = NA, scale = "column", col.main = "white",
        main = "Kenmerken Hartgezondheid", cexCol = 1.2, cexRow = 1.2, margins=c(7,5), 
        xlab = "Gerangschikt op individueel kenmerk", col.main = "#FFFFFF")
```

Comment: Goes in the direction of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839731/vary-colors-of-axis-labels-in-r-based-on-another-variable